# darknet_images.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --output ../demo_out2

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, yolo

I have trained the Yolo4 model with a custom dataset in Google Colab mounted with googlge drive. My trained model yolov4-custom_best.weights file is ready on a drive folder and I have input my training image, I want to generate output from the input images using this below code:

My last training model:

```
!./darknet detector train data/obj.data cfg/yolov4-tiny-custom.cfg yolov4-tiny.conv.29 -dont_show -map
```

My display result:

```
disp('./chart_yolov4-tiny-custom.png')
```

My test IMAGE Code: but it showing error

```
!python darknet_images.py --thresh 0.2 --input ../b076ad266891d7aa.jpg --output ../demo_out  --weights ../training/yolov4-custom_best.weights --config_file ./cfg/yolov4-custom.cfg --data_file ./data/obj.data
```

This is generating error:

```
usage: darknet_images.py [-h] [--input INPUT] [--batch_size BATCH_SIZE]
                         [--weights WEIGHTS] [--dont_show] [--ext_output]
                         [--save_labels] [--config_file CONFIG_FILE]
                         [--data_file DATA_FILE] [--thresh THRESH]
darknet_images.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --output ../demo_out
```

Don't no why is showing the error. Kindly help...

Comment: It's right there in the error message. You're executing `darknet_images.py` and passing the `--output` option, but that file does not take an `--output` option.

Comment: what should i do please, i have a little knowledge on that

Answer (score 0):

!python darknet_images.py --thresh 0.2 --input ../b076ad266891d7aa.jpg --output ../demo_out  --weights ../training/yolov4-custom_best.weights --config_file ./cfg/yolov4-custom.cfg --data_file ./data/obj.data
In this code you didn't specify the type of file in output it is jpg,mp4 etc.
I hope this will help you :)

Comment: Just one hint: It's generally not considered good practice to post an answer that consists of nothing but a link to a website. That applies even if the website actually does answer the question. The link might break in the future, some people might not have access to it, etc.